# User profile's location field doesn't autocomplete in localized sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization

Location field autocompletes in SO, MSE, *.stackexchange.com, and so on:

[image]

However, it doesn't work in ja.SO:

[image]

and pt.SO:

[image]

In this time, I saw this error in the JavaScript console.

> js:35 You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bring this to our attention.

I've updated the API keys on all international Stack Overflow sites, to ensure this works properly.